# Nginx redirects www but no non-www

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, ssl, bind

I've configured a DNS server with Bind9 in a server with `192.123.100.251` IP adress with the following configuration:

```
named.conf
==========
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";

zone "example.com" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.example.com";
    allow-transfer { none; };
    allow-query { any; };
};

zone "100.123.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.100.123.192";
    allow-transfer { none; };
    allow-query { any; };
};

db.example.com
================
$TTL 86400 ;
@   IN  SOA ns1.example.com. root.example.com. (
    1 ; 
    6H ;
    1H ;
    2W ;
    3H ;
)
@   IN  NS  ns1.example.com.
ns1 IN  A   192.123.100.251
www IN  A   192.123.100.251

db.100.123.192
=============
$TTL 86400  ;
@   IN  SOA ns1.example.com. root.example.com. (
    1   ;
    6H  ;
    1H  ;
    2W  ;
    3H  ;
)
    IN  NS  ns1.example.com.
ns1 IN  A   192.123.100.251
251 IN  PTR ns1.example.com.
```

Then I installed Nginx to have it as a reverse proxy for Tomcat (not implemented yet). I need to implement SSL so I made the following configuration:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com
======================================
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    root /var/www/example.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

/etc/nginx/snippets/self-signed.conf 
====================================
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;

/etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf 
===================================
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384;
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1; # Requires nginx >= 1.1.0
ssl_session_timeout  10m;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_tickets off; # Requires nginx >= 1.5.9
ssl_stapling on; # Requires nginx >= 1.3.7
ssl_stapling_verify on; # Requires nginx => 1.3.7
resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 5s;
# Disable strict transport security for now. You can uncomment the following
# line if you understand the implications.
# add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload";
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
```

I can access `www.example.com` and the `https` protocol seems to be successfully implemented but **I can't access** to my site through `example.com` as Chrome says *This site can't be reached*.

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

PD. I'm following this tutorials:

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-debian-10
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-on-debian-10

Comment: 192.123.100.251 is public IP space. If you're really working for Kraft Heinz you probably shouldn't be asking such questions on an open forum, especially without masking the details to an RFC1918 address in some way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting aside the public IP address issue of the question, your most obvious problem (to me) is in `db.example.com` you are missing `@   IN A 192.123.100.251`

When debugging a problem like this start with first principals

1. Can I get a dns response `dig @<nameserver> <host>` in this case `dig @ns1.example.com example.com`  (I'm intentionally ignoring the glue requirement because the hostname of the nameserver is within the domain you are querying)
2. Can you ping the server (this one is becoming less useful as people filter ICMP) but it will also confirm DNS resolution is working
3. Can you get to the site using command line tools eg `curl -vv https://example.com` some responses are too short or take too long for some browsers

Comment: Adding `@ IN A 192.123.100.251` to `db.example.com` solved the problem. Thank you.